# How do I make an array of correctly aligned, interleaved elements of two types?

Tags: c, memory-alignment

Right now, I have the following representation of B-trees:

```
#define PLUM_BTREE_MIN_COUNT  85
#define PLUM_BTREE_MAX_COUNT 170

struct bentry {
    size_t key;
    size_t value;
};

struct btree {
    size_t         count;  // number of entries being used
    struct bentry  entries [PLUM_BTREE_MAX_COUNT];
    struct btree  *children[PLUM_BTREE_MAX_COUNT + 1];
};
```

The following operation is very common:

```
struct btree src, dest;
size_t       from, to, count;
// initialized somehow

// this manipulates elements, say, 80..100
memcpy(dest->entries + to  ,
       src ->entries + from,
       count * sizeof (struct bentry));

// and then this manipulates elements 81..101
memcpy(dest->children + to   + 1,
       src ->children + from + 1,
       count * sizeof (struct btree *));
```

The two `memcpy` calls really annoy me. I wish I could store the child pointers and entries interleaved in memory, for example, like this:

```
struct btree;

struct bslot {
    struct btree  *child;
    struct bentry  entry;
};

struct btree {
    size_t        count;
    struct bslot  slots[PLUM_BTREE_MAX_COUNT];
    struct btree *child;
};
```

If alignments and paddings were never an issue, then it would be guaranteed that, for any `struct btree foo`:

```
foo.slots[PLUM_BTREE_MAX_COUNT].child == foo.child
```

So I could use a single `memcpy` call:

```
memcpy( &(dest->slots[to  ].entry),
        &(src ->slots[from].entry),
        count * sizeof (struct bslot) );
```

But, of course, alignments and paddings are sometimes an issue. Is there any way to store the child pointers and entries interleaved in memory, guaranteeing that the distance between consecutive child pointers is always a fixed constant, as in the following picture?

```
----------------------------------------------
| p0 | e0 | p1 | e1 | ... | pn | en | p{n+1} |
----------------------------------------------
|    |    |    |    |     |    |    |        |
w    x   w+k  x+k  w+2k   y    z   y+k      z+k  <--- addresses
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to use packed structs. How you achieve this depends on the compiler you are using. In gcc you make a packed struct by defining it like this:

```
struct __attribute__((__packed__)) btree
{
    size_t key;
    size_t value;
};
```

What this does is tell the compiler not to align the the struct on memory boundaries so that if you made an array of those structs, the size of the array would be exactly numberOfStructs*exactSizeOfStruct (by this I mean the size you would get if you add up all the struct's internal elements, or `sizeof()`). Any pointer arithmetic would work out exactly also.

However, this is not portable beyond GCC and must be checked with preprocessor macros.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use `struct btree __attribute__((__packed__)) {...};` (or similar with something like `#ifdef __GNUC__` and the like, though for different compilers' options) on btree, or compile without struct padding, though this depends on just how **portable** you want this to be. By declaring the struct as packed, the compiler will not mess with alignments. Otherwise, the compiler or ABI is subject to have "optimization" in their implementation. Also you could *painfully* add in some manual padding with `unsigned char pad[foo]`, if you cannot stop the compiler from changing the struct in your compilation environment.

See resources:

http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Type-Attributes.html

[Structure padding and packing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306186/structure-padding-and-structure-packing)

Answer (score 0):

Often simplest is best, and this time is no exception. (For some reason, yesterday I was just not seeing it.) I could have just used a flexible array member:

```
// These macros must be #ifdef'd to account for multiple
// architectures.  The following values work on my machine
// (x86-64 Linux).
#define PLUM_BTREE_NODE_SIZE    4096
#define PLUM_BTREE_MIN_COUNT      85
#define PLUM_BTREE_MAX_COUNT     170

struct btree;

struct bentry {
    size_t key;
    size_t value;
};

struct bslot {
    struct btree  *child;
    struct bentry  entry;
};

struct btree {
    size_t       count;
    struct bslot slots[];
};
```

And then allocated just about the right amount of memory:

```
struct btree *tree = malloc( PLUM_BTREE_NODE_SIZE );
```

And then:

- `tree->slots[i].child` is valid for any `i` from `0` to `PLUM_BTREE_MAX_COUNT`
- `tree->slots[i].entry` is valid for any `i` from `0` to `PLUM_BTREE_MAX_COUNT - 1`